# Unit testing using Jest and Enzym in React Native

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

How can I find element inside component with jest and enzyme?

Let say, I have 1 component parent (Login) and 2 child component (Title and Form), so in component Login, I want to find is there TextInput element inside Form component or something else maybe another element inside Form Component, with jest and enzyme, then how can I get that just with 1 unit testing (Login.test.js)?

This is my login component for the ilustration

```
<Login>
  <Title title='Login Page' />
  <Form 
     email={this.state.email}
     password={this.state.password}
  />
</Login>
```

Title Component

```
<Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
```

Form Component

```
<View>
  <TextInput value={this.props.email} placeHolder="Your Email" />
  <TextInput value={this.props.password} placeHolder="Your Password" />
</View>
```

This is my current Login.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Login from './Login';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('Login', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
  const instaceOf = wrapper.instance();

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const rendered = renderer.create(<Login />).toJSON();
    expect(rendered).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should render the Text Input Element', () => {
    let form = wrapper.find('Form');
    expect(form.find('TextInput"]')).toHaveLength(2);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use enzyme [`shallow`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) method, you are only rendering the first level of your component.

Therefore, the statement:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
```

is only rendering the `Title` and `Form` components but not their children.

If you want to render all the component tree, you should use [`mount`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) instead. That being said, the tests for your `Login` component should only test its first children. If you want to test that `Form` component renders two `TextInput` components, you should do so in the unit tests belonging to `Form` component (not in `Login` component).